# mingw32 posix threading library

Tags: windows, pthreads, codeblocks, mingw32

I have installed MinGW on my windows7 machine, using instructions from [here](http://mingw.org/wiki/Getting_Started). Basically I used the GUI installer assistant called mingw-get-setup.exe. The *installation manager* allowed me to select a package called `mingw32-libpthreadgc` which installs `bin/pthreadGC2.dll` and `bin/pthreadGCE2.dll`.

To my knowledge that is not sufficient to compile code depending on the pthread library. E.g. trying to compile a file with a header-include like `#include "pthread.h"` - to no surprise - results in a "file not found" compile error. I can't find that header in my MinGW directory. If I use includes/headers from elsewhere, I'm afraid they might not match with the DLL's interface. How is this meant to be working?

(Furthermore I like to use CodeBlocks as the IDE. How would I set up a simple "HelloWorld"-like pthread program to get it all to work? There seems to be a lot of conflicting messages out there on how to set it up. Use "-pthread" vs "-lpthread". Set it in compiler and linker settings, right? Copy-paste the DLL's? What else???)

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem, https://www.sourceware.org/pthreads-win32/ this did job for me,
I used this in combination with mingw32. It also has nice README file.